# Using two different brands of RAM sticks together

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have two RAM sticks, both are DDR3, the same capacity, same clock speed but come from different manufacturers. Is it fully safe to use them together in the same laptop? If any complexity, what and how to deal with it?

Comment: It will probably work but no guarantees.Mismatches like that have been known to cause problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not necessary that two different RAM sticks will not work, in a significant percent of cases they will work. Even a RAM with clock speed 1600 may work with a stick of 2400 MHz. (In such a case, both the sticks will operate on 1600 clock speed).

Similarly, two exactly the same memory sticks may fail to work together though this happens rarely. If buying a new stick, just make sure it matches with the one you have. Check for Clock speed, timing table and voltage. It is good to have all the sticks of the same capacity and to be from the same manufacturer but if not possible, there is no problem with the one from some other manufacturer.

To check all the necessary parameters, Download and install [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)