# RAM - same RAM manufacturer, but different manufacturing date and possibly chip manufacturer - could it possibly cause problems?

Tags: memory, gaming, overclocking, ddr, xmp

This question is similar to this one [Using two different brands of RAM sticks together](https://superuser.com/questions/1155386/using-two-different-brands-of-ram-sticks-together?r=SearchResults) BUT I have the same model number, RAM company is the same as well, XMP timings and XMP frequency is obviously the same as well (and voltage rating as well), but the manufacturing date is different and possibly chip manufacturer might be different.

- Is this a good idea to build in these two slightly different kits when I will be using the same XMP overclocking profile for both kits?
- Could this lead to any performance losses in gaming/benchmarks?

Comment: "Could this lead to any performance losses in gaming/benchmarks?" - No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the same model number, RAM company is the same as well, XMP
> timings and XMP frequency is obviously the same as well (and voltage
> rating as well), but the manufacturing date is different and possibly
> chip manufacturer might be different.

So long as the manufacturer says the memory is for your computer (it appears so), then it will work fine.

To your specific question, there will neither be a computer performance boost, nor any kind of degradation. The memory is specifically for your computer.

Comment: I meant to say I bought a new kit which probably has a different serial number

Comment: That should be fine as long as the manufacturer says for your computer. I have done this myself.

Comment: Well it worked and I got a 3% increase in the score on a Cinebench benchmark